# SVNParentPath directory authorization

Tags: svn, directory, authorization

The question is a bit stupid but I can't get it sorted. I have a server with SVN that uses the SVNPath directive in httpd.conf and all works fine with path authorizations. Now I'm installing a second serer where I'm going to use SVNParentPath directive and I've got it all running except I can't get the authorization part quite right. From what I understand it's the same as when you use SVNPath but you need to specificy the repo name before the folder name.. My SVNParentPath is /srv/svn/ and I created a directory /srv/svn/testproj and then ran

```
svnadmin create /srv/svn/testproj
```

Now i'm configuring my authorization file:

```
[/]
* =
svnadmin = rw
adusgi = rw

[testproj:/svn/testproj]
demada = rw
degari = rw
scarja = rw
```

Now if I try to commit /svn/testproj using user svnadmin or adusgi all is fine. If I try for example demada it doesn't work... (I've run the htpasswd2 commands for the user obviously. The directory is correct or atleast thats how I use the directory with the SVNPath server thats already running, the part I think I'm getting wrong is the repo name, I just used the directory name but what am I really supposed to put there??

Thank you, James

Comment: figured it out, correct syntax is:
[testproj:/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out, correct syntax is: [testproj:/]